# how to find the maximum value of a column dataframe in a specific POSIXct time interval in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, max, posixct

1. 

In my dataframe **CORtrial** I have two columns, **rDate** in `POSixct` format which goes from `2015-07-27 17:45:00` until `2017-08-31 16:55:00` and **REFN630** in `numeric` format. A value of **REFN630** is recorded in **rDate** in a time interval of 5 in 5 minutes.

That's the structure of my dataframe:

```
dput(head(CORtrial,10))
structure(list(rDate = structure(c(1438019100, 1438019400, 1438019700, 
1438020000, 1438020300, 1438020600, 1438020900, 1438021200, 1438021500, 
1438021800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), REFN630 = c(0.0111940298507463, 
0.0671936758893281, 0.0143198090692124, 0.0087719298245614, 0.00936768149882904, 
0.00985221674876847, 0.00775193798449612, 0.00815217391304348, 
0.00859598853868195, 0.00911854103343465)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000024f693c1ef0>)
```

I want to know the `max` value between a specific date and time interval, for instance, I want to know the MAXIMUM value of **REFN630** between the **rDate** `2015-10-23 11:25:00` and `2015-10-23 11:40:00`. How can I do this?

2)
After getting the maximum value throughout:

```
df %>%
  filter(ymd_hms(rDate) %within% 
           interval(ymd_hms("2015-07-27 22:25:00"), ymd_hms("2015-07-27 22:50:00"))) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = REFN630)

                 rDate    REFN630
1: 2015-07-27 22:25:00 0.01431981
```

More columns were added to the dataframe and the structure is the following:

```
 dput(head(COR_trial,10))
structure(list(rDate = structure(c(1438015500, 1438015800, 1438016100, 
1438016400, 1438016700, 1438017000, 1438017300, 1438017600, 1438017900, 
1438018200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), REFN532 = c(0.0127971, 
0.1348315, 0.0215983, 0.0143443, 0.0150862, 0.0158014, 0.0167866, 
0.0152284, 0.0162162, 0.0172911), REFN570 = c(0.0172414, 0.1515748, 
0.0171306, 0.0149573, 0.0157303, 0.0142518, 0.0150376, 0.016, 
0.0142045, 0.0151976), REFN630 = c(0.011194, 0.0671937, 0.0143198, 
0.0087719, 0.0093677, 0.0098522, 0.0077519, 0.0081522, 0.008596, 
0.0091185), REFN800 = c(0.0169082, 0.1030928, 0.0560472, 0.0569801, 
0.0574018, 0.0573248, 0.0531561, 0.0520833, 0.0510949, 0.0498084
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now when I use the code to get the maximum of REFN630, this is what I get:

```
COR_trial %>%
   filter(ymd_hms(rDate) %within% 
            interval(ymd_hms("2015-07-27 16:00:00"), ymd_hms("2015-07-27 18:00:00"))) %>%
   slice_max(order_by = REFN630)
                rDate   REFN532   REFN570   REFN630   REFN800
1 2015-07-27 17:50:00 0.1348315 0.1515748 0.0671937 0.1030928
```

The desired output would be:

```
 rDate   REFN630 
1 2015-07-27 17:50:00 0.0671937
```

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use the following solution. I needed to change the interval dates as the ones you mentioned on your question were not present in the data set and would lead to an empty data set after filtering. Here we first transform our preferred dates to `Date` class within `interval` function from `lubridate` package. Then we filter our data set for only those `rDate`s that fall within this interval.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  filter(ymd_hms(rDate) %within% 
           interval(ymd_hms("2015-07-27 22:25:00"), ymd_hms("2015-07-27 22:50:00"))) %>%
  summarise(Maximum = max(REFN630, na.rm = TRUE))

     Maximum
1 0.01431981
```

In order to have only the name of the column that contains max value:

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  filter(ymd_hms(rDate) %within% 
           interval(ymd_hms("2015-07-27 21:15:00"), ymd_hms("2015-07-27 21:30:00"))) %>%
  select(rDate, REFN630) %>%
  slice_max(order_by = REFN630)

                rDate   REFN630
1 2015-07-27 21:20:00 0.0671937
```

Comment: I just have an issue with the NA's. Whenever the time interval finds a NA in REFN630 the maximum number that the code gives is a NA. There any way to solve this? thank you.

Comment: Just updated my code for `NA` values. Check it please and let me know.

Comment: My pleasure glad I could help.

Comment: I have been using this code quite often. Now I would like to get the exact date and time "rDate" based on the maximum value of the column "REFN630". Any idea how I could do this?

Comment: Hello @CláudioSiva, I just made a slight modification for that purpose. Test it and let me know if there's anything I could do.

Comment: This code came out super handy for a lot of things I'm doing. Now I was wondering if there's any possibility with this code to ask for only the column of "rDate" and "REFN630". I'm asking this, because, when working with a dataframe with multiple columns, it gives me the row with the columns of interest and the rest present in the dataframe. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @CláudioSiva I didn't get your desired output, could you please explain what you expect from the output?

Comment: Let's supposed instead of 2 columns we have 6 columns. With the last code you sent the output is the row with all the columns correspondent to the max REFN630, like:  rDate    REFN630    REFN800    REFN532    REFN570    REFN400
: 2015-07-27 22:25:00 0.01431981 0.00151777 0.0816211 0.01554239 0.03411124         
      The output I want is only the rDate and REFN630 data.

Comment: @CláudioSiva I guess you could use my newest solution for this purpose. I thought we put all the columns in one column and just select the `max` value among them. In case it didn't work which is very unlikely I may need a new sample data containing those variables.

Comment: Appreciate your help, however, I didn't explain my doubt properly. I edited my question and in the 2) I tried to explain what I want with a dataframe were instead of 2 we have 5 columns. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @CláudioSiva In order to get your desired output I think it's best to select that particular column and then apply the `max` function on it. The pivot solution was fine but the output was not the way you wanted it. However, here you need to adjust the interval dates.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(rDate = as.POSIXct(rDate) %>%
   filter(between(rDate, as.POSIXct("2015-07-27 22:25:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-07-27 22:50:00")) %>%
   summarise(Max = max(REFN630))
```